# DB Connectivity from multiple modules

Tags: python, sql-server, architecture

I am working on a system where a bunch of modules connect to a MS SqlServer DB to read/write data. Each of these modules are written in different languages (C#, Java, C++) as each language serves the purpose of the module best.

My question however is about the DB connectivity. As of now, all these modules use the language-specific Sql Connectivity API to connect to the DB. Is this a good way of doing it ? 
Or alternatively, is it better to have a Python (or some other scripting lang) script take over the responsibility of connecting to the DB? The modules would then send in input parameters and the name of a stored procedure to the Python Script and the script would run it on the database and send the output back to the respective module.

Are there any advantages of the second method over the first ?

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that each language you use will have an optimized set of classes to interact with databases, then there shouldn't be a real need to pass all database calls through a centralized module.

Using a "middle-ware" for database manipulation does offer a very significant advantage. You can control, monitor and manipulate your database calls from a central and single location. So, for example, if one day you wake up and decide that you want to log certain elements of the database calls, you'll need to apply the logical/code change only in a single piece of code (the middle-ware). You can also implement different caching techniques using middle-ware, so if the different systems share certain pieces of data, you'd be able to keep that data in the middle-ware and serve it as needed to the different modules.

The above is a very advanced edge-case and it's not commonly used in small applications, so please evaluate the need for the above in your specific application and decide if that's the best approach.

Doing things the way you do them now is fine (if we follow the above assumption) :)